# How can I open encrypted sqlite database in Android?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

We have created SQLite database from .NET with encryption. Like this:

```
con.ConnectionString = "Data source = " & DB_NAME
con.Open()
con.ChangePassword(DB_PWD)
cmd = con.CreateCommand
```

Now how can I open this database in my android application? It was working fine before encrypting it. The code I am trying in android is:

```
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(ImisData.db3;Password=myPassword",null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find exactly how your .NET driver(s) are doing encryption and find or implement something compatible for android. The standard one is [sqlicpher](http://sqlcipher.net/), maybe your DB file is compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any other way to protect my db? Because my application is private so administrator will have to DB file time to time to their users. In this process I dont want someone to do some kind of tempering with the file.

Comment: If the users are actually using it, they will need the key, so it would be trivial to extract data or decrypt it. If you are just trying to protect it in transit, encrypting only the DB file, not the structured data inside (think password-protected zip) should be sufficient.

Comment: Its not the matter of protecting zip file. Its about protecting data inside. Because I tried to open db file in notepad and one can read everything in it. I won't to prevent that part.